# Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm

After integrating LDAP Authentication in jBPM, I am getting this error when I access Manage from jbpm-console:

**Attention 
Execution Server Unavailable
There is currently no server connected.**

on console I am constantly getting this error:

```
19:35:09,678 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
19:35:10,501 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/sample-server response code 405
```

When I comment out LDAP login-module from standalone.xml, it works, but not with LDAP Enabled.

Versions used:

- kie-server-7.29.0.Final-wildfly-14.0.1.Final
- jbpm-console-7.29.0.Final-wildfly-14.0.1.Final
- jbpm-casemgmt-7.29.0.Final-wildfly-14.0.1.Final

Used **jbpm-installer-7.29.0.Final** to build and start the Wildfly server.

Comment: Did you get a solution - atleast upvote one of the answers - this helps the future user

Answer (score 0):

For access to KIE Execution Server you need to have user with role 'kie-server'. I had same case. Adding user 'kieserver' with role 'kie-server'
solved my problem. Documentation of KIE Execution  Server https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch19.html

> org.kie.workbench.controller: The URL used to connect to the jBPM
>   controller, for example,
>   ws://localhost:8080/kie-server-controller/websocket/controller.
>
> org.kie.workbench.controller.user: The jBPM controller user. Default
>   value: kieserver.
>
> org.kie.workbench.controller.pwd: The jBPM controller password.
>   Default value: kieserver1!.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: userId to be used from KIE to sync should have the role of `rest-all` - the redhat exception is not encouraging !

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to configure jbpm to use DB authentication:

```
Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Error while sending PUT request to http://.... response code 405
```

The jbpm version that i'm using is: jbpm-server-7.47.0.Final-dist.zip (released at Dec 4, 2020)

In the DB, i have already setup user "admin" with password "admin" that contains the "kie-server" role.

And in the standalone.xml, i also added following system properties to define the user name and password to connect to the kie server and controller:

```
<property name="org.kie.server.user" value="admin"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.pwd" value="admin"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.user" value="admin"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.pwd" value="admin"/>
```

Even though startup the server with the mentioned error, the kie server can startup successfully. I tried to use the 'admin' user to access the kie-server REST API (e.g. GET http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server) without any problem. I also tried to login to the business central with the 'admin' user and also successful.

But the problem still remain the same that there is no server available for kjar deployment.

### Resolution

It took me several days to figure out that its the configuration issue in the standalone.xml file.

In the standalone.xml, there are by default provided a set of system properties with name is "kie.keystore.key.*". These attributes are used to retrieve the password value from the a keystore file (e.g. jBPMKeystore.jceks in the configuration folder). By checking the source code of [DefaultRestControllerImpl.java](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-services/kie-server-services-common/src/main/java/org/kie/server/services/impl/controller/DefaultRestControllerImpl.java), the logic is to first load the password from the keystore file and if there is problem, it will then retrieve the password from the system property: org.kie.server.controller.pwd

So, what we need to do is to comment out / remove the system properties "kie.keystore.*" inside the <system-properties> tag:

```
<!--
<property name="kie.keystore.keyStoreURL" value="file:///${jboss.server.config.dir}/jBPMKeystore.jceks"/>
<property name="kie.keystore.keyStorePwd" value="jBPMKeyStorePassword"/>
<property name="kie.keystore.key.server.alias" value="jBPMAlias"/>
<property name="kie.keystore.key.server.pwd" value="jBPMKeyPassword"/>
<property name="kie.keystore.key.ctrl.alias" value="jBPMAlias"/>
<property name="kie.keystore.key.ctrl.pwd" value="jBPMKeyPassword"/>
-->
```